# Пересборка пакета node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Всем доброй ночи. Подтянул `node-modules` для `Vue.js`. При загрузке странице в консоль всегда выводило информацию о пакете (p.s. китайщина). Порылся в исходниках пакета, удалил код который при старте выводил `сообщение`. Но, всё осталось по прежнему. Кто с таким сталкивался? Возможно нужно `пересобрать пакет`? `npm run dev` выполнял...

Comment: Пакет-то какой?

Comment: @diraria `wysiwyg` редактор:  [yimo-vue-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yimo-vue-editor)

Comment: Значит не удалили код, который выводит сообщение... или код появился заново?

Comment: @Дмытрык удалял код. Вчера нашёл ещё подобные строки. Китайщина усложняет жизнь)